# My titleclass breaks subsubsection headings

Tags: sectioning, templates, titlesec

I am using the `titlesec` package in conjunction with the ACM SIG Alternate document class to create a special kind of subsubsection as follows:

```
\documentclass{sig-alt-full}

% +++++ Begin Experiment Subsection ++++++
\newcommand{\subparagraph}{} % not defined in cls template
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\experiment}{straight}[\subsection]
\newcounter{experiment}
\renewcommand{\theexperiment}{(\roman{experiment})}
\titleformat{\experiment}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
        {Experiment\,(\roman{experiment}):}{.5em}{}[]
\titlespacing{\experiment}{0pt}{*2.5}{.5em}
% +++++ End Experiment Subsection ++++++

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Experiments}
\experiment{Not a Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that elsewhere in my document I want to use plain old subsubsections. However, with the definition of my new `titleclass`, the formatting of the plain old subsubsection heading looks different than before and the numbering is also gone from the heading.

How can I get my `\experiment` subsubsections while leaving the regular subsubsections untouched?

Comment: The package `titlesec` is incompatible with your class: "Non standard sectioning command detected. Using default spacing and no format." Do you want that the experiments are numbered in sequence with subsubsections?

Comment: @egreg No, I am looking for an alternative to the standard subsubsections and would like to have both environments numbered separately.

Comment: What should the number be on the left of the first `\experiment` in subsection 1.1?

Comment: @egreg The number should not be on the left. As specified in the \titleformat command, the numbering should be in the heading. It should be a '1' formatted in roman letters. 

In the above example the output should be:
"Experiment (i): Not a Subsubsection".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to forget about `titlesec` that's not compatible with the used class and to define `\experiment` in terms of `\subsubsection`:

```
\documentclass{sig-alt-full}

\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}

%%% To cope with the "non standard" way the class uses
\newfont{\experimentfnt}{ptmb8t at 11pt}

\newcounter{experiment}
\renewcommand{\theexperiment}{(\roman{experiment})}
\newcommand{\experimentname}{Experiment}

\newcommand{\experiment}[1]{%
  \subsubsection*{\refstepcounter{experiment}%
    \experimentfnt Experiment~\theexperiment: #1}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}\label{s}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\subsection{Experiments}
\experiment{Not a Subsubsection\label{ex1}}

In this experiment we do something; it is \autoref{ex1}.

\end{document}
```

The only drawback is that the label must be specified *inside* the argument. However, it seems that the class has many problems with `hyperref`, but not only: the labels are wrongly written in the `.aux` file, because `\thepage` is made equivalent to `\relax`.

I strongly suggest *not* using this class.

[image]

Comment: @janschaf Please, have a read at the FAQ (link at the top right, just left to the search box) particularly at [How do I ask questions here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: I am also using the `hyperref` package. With the above solution, `\autoref{ex1}` will produce the text "Section (i)". I would like this text to read "Experiment (i)". I tried `\newcommand{\experimentautorefname}{Experiment}`but this doesn't cut it.

Comment: Thanks, egreg. I think it should be `\subsubsection*{\refstepcounter{experiment}%`instead of `\subsection*{\refstepcounter{experiment}%`. I cannot edit your answer since this edit is smaller than 6 chars.